# x86 ASM - Read line by line

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

Okay, all I want to do is just read line by line from text and then output it.

---

***Things I do:***

- Read single char, add to string
- Search for LF
- Output string
- Do all over again until EOF

---

***Problems:***

- No idea how to count cx for 40h interrupt while It's busy with 3Fh ( tried to make some new variables, but ended up with bunch of errors )
- Some sort of odd result  - few blank lines and the very last one

---

> ***.txt example***
>
> > ```
> >     some
> >     random
> >
> >     text
> > ```

```
    .model small

    .stack  100h 

    .data 
            filename    db 255 dup(0)   
            text        db 255 dup(0)
            char        db ?
            line        db 255 dup(0)           

            filehandle  dw ?

    .code 
            newline macro    ;NEW LINE 
                             ;
            mov dl, 10       ;
            mov ah, 02h      ;                   
            int 21h          ;
                             ;
            mov dl, 13       ;
            mov ah, 02h      ;                     ;
            int 21h          ;                
            endm             ;NEW LINE
    main:   

            mov ax, @data    
            mov ds, ax   

            lea si, filename
            mov ah, 01h      ;read character

    char_input:

            int 21h         

            cmp al, 0dh      ;enter     
            je zero_terminator

            mov [si], al    
            inc si

            jmp char_input  

    zero_terminator:

            mov [si], 0 

    open_file:

            lea dx, filename         
            mov al, 0          
            mov ah, 3Dh      ;open file
            int 21h  

            mov filehandle, ax

            lea si, text   

            newline

    read_line:
            mov ah, 3Fh      ;read file
            mov bx, filehandle  
            lea dx, char         
            mov cx, 1  

            int 21h  

            cmp ax, 0       ;EOF            
            je EO_file

            mov al, char        

            cmp al, 0ah     ; line feed
            je LF  

            mov [si], al
            inc si      

            jmp read_line:

    EO_file:

            lea dx, text
            mov ah, 40h     ;print 
            mov cx, 255
            mov bx, 1       
            int 21h

            mov ah, 4ch     
            int 21h 

    LF:       
            lea dx, text
            mov ah, 40h     ;print
            mov cx, 255
            mov bx, 1

            int 21h

            inc si
            jmp read_line

     end main
```

Comment: You appear to be reading the text file one character at a time.  If you're just going to output all the lines at once at the end, why not do one big read?  You don't have anywhere near enough comments in your code, so I don't know what those DOS system calls are even supposed to do.  (Since I luckily never wrote code for DOS.)  Commenting syscall numbers with the name of the syscall would be a good start.

Comment: It's not a full program, just a beggining of it. Later I will have to find some strings from user input on each line.

Comment: Can you wait to read the file until after you have the user input?  Or if you need to keep the whole file in memory, you should probably have room for more than 255 characters!  It might be useful to tokenize it into lines while reading it, and store an array of offsets to the start of each line.  Or else you'll just have to detect newlines on the fly as you search.  Or are you packing the lines together with `'\0'` separating them, instead of newlines?  I haven't figured out how your program is designed.

Comment: Were you able to compile this code. There is an extra colon on the end of `jmp read_line:` should be `jmp read_line` . Since TASM doesn't know the size of the operands (do you want to move a byte or word?) in this statement `mov [si], 0` it should be `mov byte ptr [si], 0` since you appear to be dealing with single bytes (characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meant to get you going, not to solve all the bugs in your code:

You have:

```
zero_terminator:
        mov [si], 0
```

The idea is to move a 0 byte to the location pointed to by *SI*. *TASM* doesn't understand that you want to move a single byte to [SI] so it should be told explicitly that is what you intend:

```
        mov byte ptr [si], 0
```

You have a typo on this line with a colon on the end:

```
        jmp read_line:
```

It should be:

```
        jmp read_line
```

The primary issue with your code is that when going to print out the characters read into the `text` character array you need to specify the number of characters to print in *CX* . You specify 255 with code like this:

```
LF:
        lea dx, text
        mov ah, 40h     ;print
        mov cx, 255
```

Since *SI* contains a pointer to the last character read, you can subtract the address (offset) of *text* from *SI* to get the number of characters in the buffer. So what is above could be changed to:

```
LF:
        lea dx, text
        mov ah, 40h     ;print
        mov cx, si      ;CX = # characters. Move pointer to last char to it
        sub cx, dx      ;Subtract the offset of text (in DX) from CX
                        ;To get the actual number of chars in the buffer
```

Once you print out a line you inc *SI* and return to reading characters. Since you have printed out the line, you may as well restart from the beginning of the *text* buffer by resetting *SI* back to the start with:

```
        mov si, dx ; start from beginning of buffer (DX=beginning of text buffer)
```

or you can just mov *DX* which contains the offset of *text* already and set *SI* to it with:

This is the same way you originally set things up at the start of reading data.

The *EOF* code you have has a similar issue where it requires the number of bytes in the buffer to be placed in *ECX*. So this code:

```
EO_file:

        lea dx, text
        mov ah, 40h     ;print
        mov cx, 255
        mov bx, 1
        int 21h
```

Can be changed to:

```
LF:
        lea dx, text
        mov ah, 40h     ;print
        mov cx, si      ;CX = # characters. Move pointer to last char to it
        sub cx, dx      ;Subtract the offset of text (in DX) from CX
                        ;To get the actual number of chars in the buffer
```

With all these changes you would get a program like:

```
    .model small
    .stack  100h

    .data
            filename    db 255 dup(0)
            text        db 255 dup(0)
            char        db ?
            line        db 255 dup(0)

            filehandle  dw ?

    .code
            newline macro    ;NEW LINE
                             ;
            mov dl, 10       ;
            mov ah, 02h      ;
            int 21h          ;
                             ;
            mov dl, 13       ;
            mov ah, 02h      ;                     ;
            int 21h          ;
            endm             ;NEW LINE
    main:

            mov ax, @data
            mov ds, ax

            lea si, filename
            mov ah, 01h      ;read character

    char_input:

            int 21h

            cmp al, 0dh      ;enter
            je zero_terminator

            mov [si], al
            inc si

            jmp char_input

    zero_terminator:

            mov byte ptr [si], 0

    open_file:

            lea dx, filename
            mov al, 0
            mov ah, 3Dh      ;open file
            int 21h

            mov filehandle, ax

            lea si, text

            newline

    read_line:
            mov ah, 3Fh      ;read file
            mov bx, filehandle
            lea dx, char
            mov cx, 1

            int 21h

            cmp ax, 0       ;EOF
            je EO_file

            mov al, char

            cmp al, 0ah     ; line feed
            je LF

            mov [si], al
            inc si

            jmp read_line

    EO_file:

            lea dx, text    ;DX=offset(address) of text
            mov ah, 40h     ;print
            mov cx, si      ;CX = # characters. Move pointer to last char to it
            sub cx, dx      ;Subtract the offset of text (in DX) from CX
                            ;To get the actual number of chars in the buffer
            mov bx, 1
            int 21h

            mov ah, 4ch
            int 21h

    LF:
            lea dx, text    ;DX=offset(address) of text
            mov ah, 40h     ;print
            mov cx, si      ;CX = # characters. Move pointer to last char to it
            sub cx, dx      ;Subtract the offset of text (in DX) from CX
                            ;To get the actual number of chars in the buffer
            mov bx, 1

            int 21h

            mov si, dx      ;Start from beginning of buffer 
                            ;(DX=beginning of text buffer)
            jmp read_line

     end main
```

Comment: Perfect! `mov si, dx` is what i really needed! Thanks